# Does overflow:hidden make it block level element?

Tags: html, css

[image]

Hello I am trying to make horizontal navigation bar.

[image]

For ul I have put overflow:hidden.
For li I have put float:left.
And I have some paragraphs underneath the horizontal nav bar.

When I remove "overflow:hidden" the paragraph will move right next to my horizontal nav bar.
I do not understand why.
Can someone please explain it to me please?

Comment: can you please share your HTML , CSS ?

Comment: It's creates something called "block formatting context" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context

Answer (score 1):

No. **Never** use `overflow: hidden;` on a navbar.

`overflow: hiddenl` can hide elements that you need to be visible. so don't use it unless you **really** need it, but in this case, you don't.

Use `clear: left;` on the paragraph

```css
li { 
float:left;
padding:10px
}
ul { 
float:left;
list-style:none;
background:grey;
width:auto;
}
p { 
clear:left;
float:left;
width:100px
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>LIST</li>
  <li>LIST</li>
  <li>LIST</li>
  <li>LIST</li>
</ul>
<p>
  SOMETEXTSOMETEXTSOMETEXTSOMETEXTSOMETEXTSOMETEXTSOMETEXTSOMETEXT SOMETEXTSOMETEXTSOMETEXTSOMETEXTSOMETEXTSOMETEXT SOMETEXTSOMETEXTSOMETEXTSOMETEXT
</p>
```

or use `float: left; width: 100%;` on the `<ul>` (navigation list)

```css
li {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px
}

ul {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  background: grey;
  width: 100%;
}

p {
  float: left;
  width: 100px
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>LIST</li>
  <li>LIST</li>
  <li>LIST</li>
  <li>LIST</li>
</ul>
<p>
  SOMETEXTSOMETEXTSOMETEXTSOMETEXTSOMETEXTSOMETEXTSOMETEXTSOMETEXT SOMETEXTSOMETEXTSOMETEXTSOMETEXTSOMETEXTSOMETEXT SOMETEXTSOMETEXTSOMETEXTSOMETEXT
</p>
```

Comment: Floating everything left isn't going to help with things further down the page. Best to clear the float and then you won't need to put everything to 100%

Comment: i was `floating` the `p` only for example reasons.  if you use `float:left` and `width:100%` on the `ul` , you won't have any problems and you don't have to `float` or `100%` any other element

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: hidden;` is used to clear the floats on the li tags. Without it the paragraph butts up next to the list as the li's are floated left.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So when I'm making horizontal navigation bar is it a must to always use overflow:hidden;, and float:left?

Comment: There's multiple ways of clearing floats. Generally the most used method is called the micro clearfix which uses psuedo elements (:before, :after) to clear it. http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Comment: Thank you very much